# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'message') in Angular Login

Tags: angular, authentication, service

In my Angular 13 I have this code:

JSON Response from ASP.NET Core Web API:

```
{
   "code": 200,
   "error": false,
   "message": "Logged In Successful",
   "results": {
       "token": "thisismytoken...",
       "user": {
           "id": 1,
           "username": "Ashwel",
          },
       "roles": [
           "SuperAdmin"
       ]
   }
}
```

ANGULAR

user.ts:

```
export interface IResponse<T> {
  message: string;
  error: boolean;
  code: number;
  results: T;
}

export interface IUser 
{
  username?: string;
  token?: string;
  roles?: string[];
}
```

auth.service:

```
export class AuthService {
  baseUrl = environment.apiUrl;
  private currentUserSource = new ReplaySubject<IUser | null>(1);
  currentUser$ = this.currentUserSource.asObservable();

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private router: Router) { }
  login(model: any){
    return this.http.post(this.baseUrl+'auth/login', model).pipe(
      map((res:IUser)=>{
        const user = res;
        if(user){
          this.setCurrentUser(user);
        }
      })
    )
  }

  setCurrentUser(user: IUser){
    if(user && user.token){
      user.roles = [];
      const roles = this.getDecodedToken(user.token).role;
      Array.isArray(roles) ? user.roles = roles : user.roles.push(roles);
      localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user));
      this.currentUserSource.next(user);
    }
  }

  getDecodedToken(token: string) {
    return JSON.parse(atob(token.split('.')[1]));
  }
}
```

auth.component:

```
export class AuthComponent implements OnInit {
  loginForm!: FormGroup;
  user!: IUser | null;

  constructor(
   private authService: AuthService,
   private router: Router,
   private toastr: ToastrService
   ) {
   this.authService.currentUser$.pipe(take(1)).subscribe(user=> this.user = user);
 }

myForm() {
  this.loginForm = new FormGroup({
    UserName: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    Password: new FormControl('', [Validators.required])
  })
}

login(){
  this.authService.login(this.loginForm.value).subscribe({
    next: (res: any) => {
      console.log(res);
      this.toastr.success(res.message);
      this.router.navigateByUrl('dashboard');
    },
    error: (error) => {
      this.toastr.error(error.message);
    }
  })
 }
}
```

This is the flow `auth.component` -> `auth.service` -> `user.ts`:

What I intend to do is, when user submits to login:

1. token, username and roles are stored in the `localStorage`
2. when login is successful, it displays the message: Logged In successful
3. it redirects to dashboard

But instead of all these, I got this error in the inspect -> console:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'message')

When I did console.log(res) in `auth.service`, I got undefined.

How do I resolve this error?

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried using chain operator `?` since it is asynchronous --> `this.toastr.success(res?.message)`

Comment: @Chaka15 - When I did as you explain, it redirects to the dashboard but certain issues occur.   1. There is nothing in the this.toastr.success.     2. It doesn't store the token, username and roles in the localstorage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two mistakes in your `AuthService.login` method:

- You have the response label as `IUser` when based on the JSON you've posted it should be of `IResponse<IUser>>`
- You are using the `map` operator to trigger a side effect. `map` is used to apply a transformation to the emitted values and therefore the map function should return the transform value. To trigger side effects you should use `tap`.

So you should modify the method as follows.

```
login(model: any){
  return this.http.post<IResponse<IUser>>(this.baseUrl+'auth/login', model).pipe(
    tap((response) => {
      const user = response.results;
      if(user){
        this.setCurrentUser(user);
      }
    })
  )
}
```

cheers

Comment: I now see the message. But why is it not storing username, roles and token in the localStorage?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your `map pipe` in `AuthService.login` method should return data

```
login(model: any){
  return this.http.post(this.baseUrl+'auth/login', model).pipe(
    map((res:IUser) => {
      const user = res;
      if(user){
        this.setCurrentUser(user);
      }
      return res; // <- here
    })
  )
}
```

Pipe documentation https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/map

Comment: But I find some mis-typing, like `IUser` doesn't has `message` property